# What is the name of paper to train how to write kanji?

Tags: kanji, word-requests, genkōyōshi

I'm learning how to write hiragana, katakana and kanji.

What is the name of paper that has little squares to write the Japanese characters?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is on-topic, but do you mean [原稿用紙](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genk%C5%8D_y%C5%8Dshi)?

Comment: Something like this? http://happylilac.net/sy-ntka.html You can find more -> https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E7%B7%B4%E7%BF%92%E7%94%A8%E7%B4%99&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=-goRV_vdNMOq0QTBl6HwDw

Comment: You also might want to look up 漢字ドリル.

Comment: I rarely need it, but usually 漢字練習帳 finds what I'm looking for. I don't know of a specific word though.

Comment: I  already found !! Tanks  for all!

Answer (score 6):

This kind of paper is called [原稿用紙](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8E%9F%E7%A8%BF%E7%94%A8%E7%B4%99), used in composition class or by professional writers, but for practical writing rather than training (generally too small for training).

[image]

The format below is dedicated to kanji training (but also good for kana). While it doesn't have fixed name, notebooks that bind these sheets are sold in the name of [漢字練習帳](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E7%B7%B4%E7%BF%92%E5%B8%B3&tbm=isch).

[image]